# SQL restrict one column in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to restrict the results for column `count(rm_ca) as office` to be `rm_ca ='1'`
I can't put this into the `where` clause as I don't want the other fields restricted. only that one column. How can this be done?

```
SELECT count(distinct bl) as bld, 
       count(rm) as rooms, 
       sum(area) as total_area, 
       count(rm_ca) as office 
FROM table 
WHERE dp= '345';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN rm_ca = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS office
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   SELECT count(distinct bl) as bld, 
   count(rm) as rooms, 
   sum(area) as total_area, 
   count(decode (rm_ca,1,0)) as office 
   FROM table 
   WHERE dp= '345';
```

To learn more about Decode read [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)